# How to set null to field in graphql?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

We use graphql on our project and use graphql-java 2.3.0 (we plan to update but it is not possible at the moment).

I'm trying to perform such mutation:

```
  mutation {
    UPDATE_User(

      id:3,
      type: null
    ) {id}
  }
```

Response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "validationErrorType": "WrongType",
      "message": "Validation error of type WrongType: argument value EnumValue{name='null'} has wrong type",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 7
        }
      ],
      "errorType": "ValidationError"
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null keyword is a relatively new addition to the GraphQL spec, and the graphql-java version you're using doesn't yet have it implemented. In fact, even 3.0.0 still doesn't have it. The soon-to-be-released 4.0 will have support for the null keyword.
And the reason it is treated as an enum is because unquoted strings are normally enums, `null` being the only exception. This is also explained in [this issue](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/578).

Comment: I see. Thank you. But what is the reccomended workaround? I don't think that null was not used by graphql users until now.

Comment: @Don_Quijote Null was only added months ago. Prior to that, all you could do was not send `type` at all, but then you can't distinguish _update to null_ and _leave unchanged_ cases. If this is important to you, you'll have to set a special marker value to `type` e.g. `type: "NONE"` and handle that appropriately in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema, is 'type' parameter required ?

If not then simply omit it ! On your backend when you will retrieve the value of `type`then it will be null